# Web Application + RestAPI for Mobile

Tags: rest, yii2

I’m new to Yii2.
I was wondering what would be a better choice, to use advanced or basic template if I needed to create an web application that also provides a Rest API for the mobile version.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the advance or basic app you would need to set up a separate application for the `API` as you won't get it bundled in the any of the apps (basic or advanced) when installing via composer.

- You can read the Docs for [Adding More Apps](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-adding-more-apps.md) which describes how you can add more apps other than `frontend` and `backend`.
- Then you can go through the [Budi Irawan's Tech Blog](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/)  which gives a nice step by step tutorial to add an API application to your `yii2-advance-app`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need the advanced one because to follow some good practices you should separate the different business logics and for that the advanced template is very good

Example :

- / common: here you have to put all your code that will be shared
  between the web application and your Api, it is a good place to put the models.
- / backend: here you have to go all the logic related to the views of
  your backend, controllers, helpers, component ....
- / frontend: here all the logic related to the views of your
  frontend, controllers, helpers, component ...
- / api: here all the logic related  of your api,
  controllers, helpers, component .... and it is very likely that in
  the future you want to implement a system of versions for your api,
  and here would be the site appropriate (/ api / v1, / api / v2, ...)

(Article) How to create api in Yii2 [url](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!